# How to log into Facebook programmatically using Java?

Tags: java, html, facebook, cookies, post

I'm trying to write a Java program that can automatically log into Facebook.

I've got the below code so far that downloads the home html page into a String but don't know how to send the email and password to log into Facebook? Also will the Java program need to handle cookies returned to remain logged in?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.facebook.com/");
        URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc
                .getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        String allInput = "";

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {

            allInput += inputLine + "\r\n";
        }
        System.out.println(allInput);

        in.close();
    }
```

}

**Update:**

I've tried the below code using htmlUnit however I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ElementNotFoundException:     elementName=[form] attributeName=[name] attributeValue=[login_form] at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.getFormByName(HtmlPage.java:588)
```

Anyone know why this is?

```
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://www.facebook.com");
    final HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("login_form");

    final HtmlSubmitInput button = (HtmlSubmitInput) form.getInputsByValue("Login").get(0);
    final HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("email");
    textField.setValueAttribute("jon@jon.com");
    final HtmlTextInput textField2 = form.getInputByName("pass");
    textField2.setValueAttribute("ahhhh");
    final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
```

Comment: But i'm getting some exceptions like Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/protocol/ProtocolSocketFactory. Can you specify which version of Htmlunit jar is to be downloaded just to make sure that I did the right thing

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should take a look at HTMLUnit, it'll be much simpler than using the above.  The following page and code should guide you:

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://www.facebook.com");
final HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("login_form");

final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputsByValue("Log in");
final HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("email");
textField.setValueAttribute("jon@jon.com");
final HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("pass");
textField.setValueAttribute("ahhhh");
final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
```

http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried the code (see update above) however I get an element not found exception for the login form for some reason? Any idea why?

Comment: It's the first form on the page so you should be able to get it via the getForms()[0] method.  You might have trouble submitting the form, but I'm sure it's possible via HttpUnit.

Comment: And how do you get returned data, like session token, with this?

Comment: it is showing some sort of exceptions when i used the above code...Exception in thread "main" com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ElementNotFoundException: elementName=[form] attributeName=[name] attributeValue=[UIFullPage_Container] what the error in my code..Plz help me

Comment: I'm getting error "Cannot resolve symbol 'WebClient'", how to use this with pom.xml ?

Comment: This doesn't work in 2022, not able to login to https://www.valueresearchonline.com/login, using above solution

Answer (score 13):

There are some problems in your code

1. is that `login_form` is not the form name but the form ID
2. the submit button value i `Log In`
3. type of password field is `HtmlPasswordInput`

so:

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://www.facebook.com");
final HtmlForm form = (HtmlForm) page1.getElementById("login_form");

final HtmlSubmitInput button = (HtmlSubmitInput) form.getInputsByValue("Log In").get(0);
final HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("email");
textField.setValueAttribute("jon@jon.com");
final HtmlPasswordInput textField2 = form.getInputByName("pass");
textField2.setValueAttribute("ahhhh");
final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
```

Comment: thanks for the code.. helped me in resolving the errors with earlier verison