# Facebook login with HTTPSUrlConnection pure, without an API

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, https, facebook-login

Some way to save tokens without a Facebook API? I want to login on Facebook using native Java libraries. As Mozilla does!

If I set my correct login infos, the 'facebook.com' returns the home page. If I set incorrectly logins, he returns a page of 'you email or password is incorr...'
Why he do not returns my home page, with a friends and etc... ?

Here is the code:

```
String httpsURL = "https://www.facebook.com/login.php";

    String query;
    try {
        String MY_MAIL = "YOUR MAIL";
        String MY_PASS = "YOUR PASS";

        query = "lsd=AVpivkhO&email=" + URLEncoder.encode(MY_MAIL, "UTF-8") + "&pass=" + URLEncoder.encode(MY_PASS, "UTF-8") + "&default_persistent=0&timezone=180&lgndim=eyJ3IjoxMzY2LCJoIjo3NjgsImF3IjoxMzY2LCJhaCI6NzM4LCJjIjoyNH0%3D&lgnrnd=135513_yy32&lgnjs=1441832114&locale=pt_BR&qsstamp=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";
        //query = "";

        URL myurl = new URL(httpsURL);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)myurl.openConnection();

        con.setRequestMethod("POST");

        con.setRequestProperty("Host", "facebook.com");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0;Windows98;DigExt)"); 
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
        //con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        con.setRequestProperty("Cookie:", "fr=0DlGgNm7j7OSrxwX6.AWVtGD2R_8r7u9v6SmEp-u_cTWA.BVmtC5.sI.AAA.0.AWV7nB8J; lu=RAJEHG-pWh91KhTp4yKcf40A; datr=n9CaVRge8gdmQM4fbYPCgerZ; locale=pt_BR; a11y=%7B%22sr%22%3A0%2C%22sr-ts%22%3A1441880544006%2C%22jk%22%3A0%2C%22jk-ts%22%3A1441880544006%2C%22kb%22%3A1%2C%22kb-ts%22%3A1441880544006%2C%22hcm%22%3A0%2C%22hcm-ts%22%3A1441880544006%7D; reg_fb_ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F%3Fstype%3Dlo%26jlou%3DAfeJdlzS3ToJP2-zmWuo749IArqE_LKyQPhyMJUZGzXJ04e7NsDHRllozvz1i-L_gVMnR55t3_-GIBPa9s1jrq1eNyoO43bYSUV4YqOC04TPGg%26smuh%3D50695%26lh%3DAc9epmfRhrK0i_WU; reg_fb_gate=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F%3Fstype%3Dlo%26jlou%3DAfeJdlzS3ToJP2-zmWuo749IArqE_LKyQPhyMJUZGzXJ04e7NsDHRllozvz1i-L_gVMnR55t3_-GIBPa9s1jrq1eNyoO43bYSUV4YqOC04TPGg%26smuh%3D50695%26lh%3DAc9epmfRhrK0i_WU; wd=1525x268");
        con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");

        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setDoOutput(true);

        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());  

        output.writeBytes(query);

        output.close();

        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream( con.getInputStream() ); 

        for( int c = input.read(); c != -1; c = input.read()){
            System.out.print( (char)c ); 
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(">> " + con.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie"));

        input.close(); 

        System.out.println("Resp Code:"+con .getResponseCode()); 
        System.out.println("Resp Message:"+ con .getResponseMessage());
        //System.out.println("coo: " + coo.get(1));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm using Mozilla to analyze the Network HTTP Headers/Requests and Standards, and to get Cookies.

Further questions:

1 - The browser generates the Cookie?

2 - Who first sends cookies, client or server?

3 - What is needed for a successful login? Tokens, cookies... ?

OBS: I already know programming, I'm a good programmer. This is a matter of protocol and standardization. So please respect my doubt and the knowledge.

________________________ EDIT ____________________

This code is similar to mine code. I wanted to do something in that style: [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-automate-login-a-website-java-example/)

_______________________ EDIT 2 _____________________

I do not want to use API, but the HTMLUnit looks interesting and no frills.
Looks: [How to log into Facebook programmatically using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285250/how-to-log-into-facebook-programmatically-using-java)

Comment: Looks like you don't know HTTP well. Cookies are always set by the server using the `Set-Cookie` response header.

Comment: I know high-level and kernels. But HTTP is a international pattern (not is my codes).
Is the first time I felt interest in know the data structure of the HTTP. Is a normal IPv4 communication.

Why is it that the server does not respond to the login page, but points error if the password is incorrect? What sense?

Comment: More infos about this?