# HTMLUnit/Java - Form is not found

Tags: java, html, forms, htmlunit

I have very recently started using HTMLUnit. My goal is to automate logging into another website (I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285250/how-to-log-into-facebook-programmatically-using-java) as my guide). However, my code is unable to find the form (of the website I am trying to log into) by ID, even though I gave it the forms id.

Website Form HTML Code:

```
<form id="site-login-form" action="/podium/blank.html">
```

My code:

```
        final HtmlForm form = (HtmlForm) page1.getElementById("site-login-form");
                System.out.println("Found form");
                System.out.println(form);
```

**When I try to print the form data (as seen above), null is printed instead.**

I would really appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: What is the class name for page1 ?

Can you check that form is not null.  Would this be the case if page1.getElementById("site-login-form") returned null if it couldn't find the "form" on the page?

Comment: I chased it down and the getElementById will return null if it can't find the ID on the page.  Are you certain that the page you are looking at does have that id?

Comment: @MikeMurphy yeah I literally copied and pasted that code from the websites html.

Comment: Did you find out what the issue was?

Comment: @MikeMurphy Not yet Im still searching

Comment: @MikeMurphy is there maybe another way to automate logging into a website without using forms?

Comment: Do you mean logging or submitting? Can you attach more of your unit test code, that might help to identify what's not working.